# discordjs how to console log message without dms

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would my bot to print messages sent to a server, but when that bot has been sent a dm it prints it.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(chalk.yellow(`[CHAT] `) + 
        chalk.bold.magentaBright(`[${message.guild.name}] `) + 
        chalk.bold.white(`User: ${message.author.username} ` +
            `Said: ${message.content} In: ${message.channel.name}`))
    }
});
```

Comment: could you clarify: what do you see happening? And your question? You want your bot to print DM messages it received, and it doesn't right now, is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ignore all DM message from users

```
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
```

Add it to `bot on message block`

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
console.log(chalk.yellow([CHAT]) + chalk.bold.magentaBright([${message.guild.name}]) + chalk.bold.white(User: ${message.author.username} Said: ${message.content} In: ${message.channel.name})) } 
});
```